# Issue with external connection from server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Faced with situation that nginx+php-fpm has stopped retrieving content from external resources (like, Amazon API), even file_get_content/curl (PHP) are failing with timeout errors.

```
# wget --debug "URL"
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = `UTF-8'
--2018-01-31 11:24:54--  URL
Resolving URL (URL)... , ...
Caching URL => ...
Connecting to URL (URL)|...|:80... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to URL (URL)|...|:80... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to URL (URL)|...|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000001bd97c0 (new refcount 1).
```

Does anyone have ideas about issue itself and possible steps to resolve it, or at least to debug it for clarification?

Comment: Run it with strace to get even more debug output. My initial guess is that could be blocked in a firewall.

Comment: @pkhamre, `traceroute`, `mtr`, and `ping` are working fine; but not `wget`. and I'm totally lost in resolving that issue.

Comment: Same with curl? I mean the problem is with the connection and not the program?

Comment: Yes, the same issue

Comment: @pkhamre, taken response that IPv6 has been changed for my server, but not the linux configs. Any time when I'm trying to reset them by using `ip route del/add`, became disconnected...